# Akka Clustering is not working

Tags: akka-cluster

I am trying to learn Akka Clustering following the tutorial provided [here](https://tersesystems.com/blog/2014/06/25/akka-clustering/)

I have created the app and the repo is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/AkkaClusteringTerseSystems).

As mentioned in the tutorial I have started the FrontEndApp

```
> runMain TransformationFrontendApp
[info] Running TransformationFrontendApp 
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:05.293] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:05.543] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:54746]
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:05.556] [run-main-0] 
[akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:54746] - Starting up...
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:05.648] [run-main-0] 
[akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:54746] - Registered cluster JMX MBean 
[akka:type=Cluster]
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:05.648] [run-main-0] 
[akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:54746] - Started up successfully
[WARN] [10/31/2017 17:28:05.683] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] 
[WARN] [10/31/2017 17:28:05.748] [New I/O boss #3] 
[NettyTransport(akka://ClusterSystem)] Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:2551
[WARN] [10/31/2017 17:28:05.750] [New I/O boss #3] 
[NettyTransport(akka://ClusterSystem)] Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:2552
[WARN] [10/31/2017 17:28:05.751] [ClusterSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-12]        [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:54746/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClusterSystem%40127.0.0.1%3A2551-0] Association with remote system [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:2551]
```

The above warn message repeats continuously  even after I start the Backend App on 2551 and 2552.

The terminal log of starting backend actor on 2551.

```
> runMain TransformationBackendApp 2551
[info] Running TransformationBackendApp 2551
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:50.867] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:51.122] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2551]
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:51.134] [run-main-0] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2551] - Starting up...
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:51.228] [run-main-0] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2551] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:51.228] [run-main-0] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2551] - Started up successfully
[WARN] [10/31/2017 17:28:51.259] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2551/system/cluster/core/daemon/downingProvider] Don't use auto-down feature of Akka Cluster in production. See 'Auto-downing (DO NOT USE)' section of Akka Cluster documentation.
[   ERROR] [10/31/2017 17:28:51.382] [ClusterSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] [akka://ClusterSystem/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClusterSystem%40localhost%3A2551-2/endpointWriter] dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2551]
```

The last `[Error]` log repeats continuously.

The terminal log of starting backend actor on 2552.

```
> runMain TransformationBackendApp 2552
[info] Running TransformationBackendApp 2552
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.451] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.689] [run-main-0] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552]
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.706] [run-main-0] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552] - Starting up...
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.803] [run-main-0] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.803] [run-main-0] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552] - Started up successfully
[WARN] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.836] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552/system/cluster/core/daemon/downingProvider] Don't use auto-down feature of Akka Cluster in production. See 'Auto-downing (DO NOT USE)' section of Akka Cluster documentation.
[WARN] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.909] [New I/O boss #3] [NettyTransport(akka://ClusterSystem)] Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:2551
[WARN] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.910] [ClusterSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-13] [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClusterSystem%40127.0.0.1%3A2551-0] Association with remote system [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:2551]
[INFO] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.914] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://ClusterSystem/deadLetters] Message [akka.cluster.InternalClusterAction$InitJoin$] from Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/system/cluster/core/daemon/joinSeedNodeProcess-1#-937368711] to Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[ERROR] [10/31/2017 17:28:25.958] [ClusterSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-17] [akka://ClusterSystem/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClusterSystem%40localhost%3A2552-2/endpointWriter] dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552]
```

Not sure what is the reason `backend` cluster nodes are not able to detect each other and `frontend` actor node with back end.

Do I miss any settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your application.conf. You have akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname = "localhost" and akka.cluster.seed-nodes=["akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551", "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]. You have to use either localhost or 127.0.0.1, not both:

```
akka {

  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "localhost"
      port = 0
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2551", "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552"]
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
  }

}
```